# wicked-pdf: Error: PDF could not be generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, bundler, production-environment, wicked-pdf

I am trying to create pdf order receipts on our app (on Heroku). I am running the PDF generator as a delayed job.
I have: 
-created a bin folder in the root of the app
-added the binaries (x86-64) to that folder
-added wicked pdf gem to my gemfile

I am testing it on our staging app.

This is the error I'm getting:

`Error: Failed to execute:
["/app/vendor/bundle/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q", "--page-size", "Letter", "file:///tmp/wicked_pdf20141022-213-3dpi58.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20141022-213-1tqzjod.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:305:in 'block in replace_bin_path': undefined method name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/wkhtmltopdf:16:in`

Any ideas on what may be going on here? I'm at bit of a loss.

CODE:

```
#config/initializers/wicked-pdf.rb

WickedPdf.config do |config|  
  if Rails.env == 'production' then
   config.exe_path = Rails.root.to_s + "/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64"
  else 
   if /darwin/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM then
      config.exe_path = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf' 
    else
      raise "UnableToLocateWkhtmltopdf"
    end
  end
end
```

I'm calling to queue the job in my order controller

```
#jobs/pdf_receipt_job

class PdfReceiptJob < Struct.new(:order_id)

def perform

    order = Order.find(order_id)

    # create an instance of ActionView, so we can use the render method outside of a controller
    view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {})
    html_template = view.render(file: "order/receipt_attachment.html.erb", locals:{order:order})

    # use wicked_pdf gem to create PDF from the HTML receipt template
    pdf_receipt = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html_template, :page_size => 'Letter')

    # save PDF to disk. Later, to be stored in fog, sent to S3, than saved back to our DB
    pdf_path = Rails.root.join("tmp", "marmoset-receipt#{order.id}.pdf") #ex: will be at tmp/marmoset-receipt215.pdf

    File.open(pdf_path, 'wb') do |file|
      file << pdf_receipt
    end

    end
end
```

The receipt template (to become PDF receipt):

```
#views/order/receipt_attachment.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
        <title>Order Receipt from Marmoset</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>

    <body>

      <div style="width: 75%">
        <header>
          <div style="display: inline; width:100%">
            <img src="http://stillmotionblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/RGB-marmoset-seal-purple.png" alt="Marmoset" style="height: 200px; padding:20; float:left">
            <h3 style="font-family: Helvetica; float:right; color:gray;">Order Number: <%= order.id %></br>
              Charge Key: <%= order.stripe_charge_key %>
            </h3>

          </div>
        </header>
        <div style="margin: 0 auto">
          <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" summary="Order Receipt" width="100%" style="font-family: Georgia;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th bgcolor="#8A4FAB" style="color:white" scope="col">Track</th>
                <th bgcolor="#8A4FAB" style="color:white" scope="col">License</th>
                <th bgcolor="#8A4FAB" style="color:white" scope="col">Price</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody style="font-family: Georgia;">
              <% order.line_items.each do |line_item| %>
                <tr>
                  <td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" style="font-family: Georgia; color: #5C5C5C"><%= line_item.track.display_name %></td>
                  <td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" style="font-family: Georgia; color: #5C5C5C"><%= line_item.license.display_name %></td>
                  <td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" style="font-family: Georgia; color: #5C5C5C"><%= number_to_currency line_item.price %></td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;font-family: Georgia; color: #5C5C5C">Subtotal</td>
                  <td style="font-family: Georgia; color: #5C5C5C"><%= number_to_currency order.price %></td>
                </tr>
              <% if order.discount > 0 %>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;font-family: Georgia; color: #5C5C5C">Discount</td>
                  <td style="font-family: Georgia; color: #5C5C5C">-<%= number_to_currency order.discount %></td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>


              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;font-family: Georgia; color: #5C5C5C ">Total</td>
                <td style="font-family: Georgia; color: #5C5C5C"><%= number_to_currency order.total %></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <hr style="margin: 30px 0px 30px 0px">
        <p style="font-family: Georgia; color: #5C5C5C">Licensing information for your order:</p>
        <ul style="font-family: Georgia; color: #5C5C5C">

          <% order.line_items.map{|l| l.license}.uniq.each do |license| %>
            <li><strong><%= license.name %> <%= "(#{license.range.html_safe})" if license.range.present? %>:</strong>
              <ul>
                <% if license.permitted_content.present? %>
                  <li>
                    <b>Permitted Content:</b>
                      <%= license.permitted_content.html_safe %>
                  </li>
                <% end %>
                <% if license.non_permitted_content.present? %>
                  <li>
                    <b>Non-Permitted Content:</b>
                       <%= license.non_permitted_content.html_safe %>
                  </li>
                <% end %>
                <% if license.number_of_uses.present? %>
                  <li>
                    <b>Number of Uses:</b>
                      <%= license.number_of_uses %>
                  </li>
                <% end %>
                <% if license.distribution.present? %> 
                  <li>
                    <b>Distribution:</b>
                      <%= license.distribution %>
                  </li>
                <% end %>  
                <% if license.term.present? %>
                  <li>
                    <b>Lifespan:</b>
                      <%= license.term %>
                  </li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>

          <p style="font-family: Georgia; font-size: .9em; color:gray; font-style:italic; padding: 5px; margin-top:30px; text-align: center">
            Thank you for supporting our family of musicians with your purchase. Your purchase makes an impact on the lives of hard working, blue collar artists. We hope you enjoy the music and we can't wait to see what stories you tell. Give us a shout at <a style="text-decoration: none" href="mailto:compass@marmosetmusic.com" target="_blank"><span style="color:#8A4FAB; font-style: normal">compass@marmosetmusic.com</span></a> to share your masterpiece when it's finished.</p>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

EDIT: if I run `wkhtmltopdf www.marmosetmusic.com myhomepage.pdf` in my terminal, it works locally, if I log into the bash of my heroku app and run this, I get the same error     `/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:305:in 'block in replace_bin_path': undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/wkhtmltopdf:16:in`'`

Comment: Looks like it might be related to your binstubs. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24840517/23915

Comment: @Unixmonkey Thanks. I tried that and still have the same issue. So I started fresh with a new bin folder with only the binary file in there, push to staging, and it seems to add all this stuff when I deploy. `Dir.entries('bin')
=> [".", "ri", "gem", "wkhtmltopdf-amd64", "node", "irb", "erb", "rake", "rdoc", "testrb", "ruby.exe", "..", "ruby"]`. When I run that locally, there is only the binary file (wkhtmltopdf-amd64). Hmmmmm.

Comment: Please include the _full_ error backtrace.

Comment: Could you solve this?

Comment: @Reinhold Yes. It took some wrangling, but I got it all working now. I removed binaries, reinstalled wkhtmltppdf, re-added the binaries, and got it working.