# undefined method `plain_specs' for #<Bundler::RubygemsIntegration:0x00005633f09a9000> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have made a pull of a project that I have in my work and when I tried to run `rails db:migrate`, the terminal request to install "Bundler 2" so I do it.

Now, when I tried to do `rails db:migrate` I have the following error:

```
/home/acartesc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:84:in `setup': undefined method `plain_specs' for #<Bundler::RubygemsIntegration:0x00005633f09a9000> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/acartesc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:124:in `check'
    from /home/acartesc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:131:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/acartesc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `require'
    from /home/acartesc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/acartesc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:178:in `require'
    from /home/acartesc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/acartesc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.5.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `block in run'
    from /home/acartesc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.5.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /home/acartesc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.5.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
    from /home/acartesc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10:in `<main>'
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: The problem seems similar to the one described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833123/custom-gem-execution-fails-with-nomethoderror which is solved by regenerating the binstubs.

Comment: Regenerating binstubs didn't help. I downgraded bundler to 2.0.2 and everything works fine now. I guess it's a bundler 2.1.0 bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
gem uninstall rubygems-bundler
```

works for me
I am using bundler 2.1.0

REF: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/7492

When showing

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    rubygems-bundler is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
    gem uninstall -i /Users/xxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0 rubygems-bundler
```

Please run

```
gem uninstall -i /Users/xxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0 rubygems-bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your ruby version? I had same problem.

My ruby version is `2.6.3` and my bundle didn't work in this ruby version.
(Bundle is already upgraded to `2.0.2`),

So I downgraded my bundle to verion `1.17.3` and it worked.

I with this solution will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using a version of ruby that is supported. I ran into this when trying to use `jruby-9.2.9`. By switching from jruby to ruby the problem went away.

```
rvm use ruby-2.5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug with bundler version `2.1.0.pre.2`

I unistalled bundler gem and install different version of bundler gem

```
$ gem uninstall bundler
$ gem install bundler -v 2.0.2
```

It should work.