# NoMethodError: undefined method `plain_specs' for #<Bundler::RubygemsIntegration

Tags: ruby, sinatra, jruby

I am new to actually very new. I am trying to run sinatra with jruby below is the tutorail I am try to follow,

http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/1325/getting-started-with-jruby-webapps-using-rack-and-sinatra/

I have installed everything accordingly but I am getting an exception below.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.util.SecurityHelper to field java.lang.reflect.Field.modifiers
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.util.SecurityHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
NoMethodError: undefined method `plain_specs' for #<Bundler::RubygemsIntegration:0x55b62629 @replaced_methods={}>
    setup at /home/jahanzeb/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:84
    check at /home/jahanzeb/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:124
   <main> at /home/jahanzeb/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:131
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:984
   (root) at /home/jahanzeb/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
  require at /home/jahanzeb/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.6.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135
   <main> at /home/jahanzeb/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4
     each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1792
      run at /home/jahanzeb/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50
   <main> at /home/jahanzeb/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.6.0/bin/jruby_executable_hooks:10
```

I have gone through the related question but no results.
Please help

Comment: please, show us the exact code you're trying to run

Comment: This seems to be related to bundler, check this out please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366604/undefined-method-plain-specs-for-bundlerrubygemsintegration0x00005633f09a There is a recommendation to downgrade bundler. The error comes from [rubygems bundler source code](https://github.com/rvm/rubygems-bundler/blob/d55d5969b5b036c6ee4797049e49aab40dca4774/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb#L84)

Comment: @mrzasa I am following the exact same tutorial which is at the link http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/1325/getting-started-with-jruby-webapps-using-rack-and-sinatra/

Comment: @Christian I have downgraded my bundler gem to 1.x.x and to 2.0.2 as well but no luck so far.

Comment: @Jahanzeb I have no idea what step caused this issue, so I can't help you.

Comment: I'd reinstall everything and start over with another tutorial, e.g. http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/deployment/jruby? Was able to run this on my Mac.