# Ruby On Rails stop working!! It doesn't accept any commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

No matter what I do (ex: `rails -v`), it gives me that error

```
ruby -v => ruby-2.6.3

rails -v => 6.0.1
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    6: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10:in `<main>'
    5: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
    4: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    3: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `block in run'
    2: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    1: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems-bundler/noexec (LoadError)
    10: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10:in `<main>'
     9: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
     8: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
     7: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `block in run'
     6: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     5: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:156:in `require'
     4: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `rescue in require'
     3: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `require'
     2: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:131:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:124:in `check'
/home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:84:in `setup': undefined method `plain_specs' for #<Bundler::RubygemsIntegration:0x0000559d9898f978> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: The error says: *"undefined method `plain_specs'"....*. The very first thing I would do is google the error message. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59366604/1954610) is the top result. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it is working. thanks :)

Comment: The solution https://stackoverflow.com/q/59366604/1954610

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `bundle update`?
Maybe reinstalling the gems could help, from the error I see there is a `ruby-2.6.3` and inside that folder a `gems/2.6.0/`.

Comment: $ bundle update
Could not locate Gemfile

Comment: i will try reinstalling the gems

Comment: the same problem, this error prevents me from creating a new app also